# Defined product custom field value replace price on WooCommerce loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, price

On my WooCommerce products I would like to replace product price by the product model reference custom field **(ex: #AB2568B)**. How to display the model reference instead of the price? Any help please.

[image: link]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply I have products on which I have custom model no or you can say ID of product which is decided by us I want to show product model number instead of product cost which is showing in above image ..... please check image it will help you to understand    [link](https://snipboard.io/hqjuD8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't give any detail on your product custom field, The code below will add a custom field to admin single product settings.

Then when this custom field will have a defined value, it will replace the product price:

```
// Admin product general settings: Display a custom field (below prices)
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_product_general_setting_field' );
function add_product_general_setting_field() {
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'                => '_reference_id',
        'label'             => __( 'Reference Id', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'       => __( 'Please enter the model reference Id', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'       => __( 'Please enter the model reference Id', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}

// Admin product general settings: Save custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_product_general_setting_field' );
function save_product_general_setting_field( $product ){
    if(isset($_POST['_reference_id']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_reference_id', sanitize_texT_field( $_POST['_reference_id']) );
    }
}

// replace loop product price by the model reference Id
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_after_shop_loop_item_title_callback', 9 );
function action_after_shop_loop_item_title_callback() {
    global $product;

    $reference_id = $product->get_meta('_reference_id');

    if( ! empty($reference_id) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 ); // remove the price

        // Display the model reference
        echo '<span class="price regerence_id">'.$reference_id.'</span>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]